# Encode text to JavaScript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, encoding

I'm trying to pass a text to my JavaScript function as bellow.

```
hplDetails.NavigateUrl = "JavaScript:GetSpecialEquipmentsDetails('" + ((SGViagens.Entities.SpecialEquipment)(e.Item.DataItem)).EquipmentCode + "','" + ((SGViagens.Entities.SpecialEquipment)(e.Item.DataItem)).EquipmentName + "')";
```

My second parameter contains any text with accents, special characters. But when I get in my JavaScript function, the text is mangled.
Anyone have any tips for me?

Comment: Could you show what the text looks like in C# and in JS?

Comment: in C# is 'Assento para Bebês', in JS show me Assentos%20para%20beb%C3%83....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `<asp:HyperLink>` try having such thing:

```
<a id="hplDetails" runat="server">Text here</a>
```

Then assign its URL with such code:

```
hplDetails.Attributes["href"] = "URL here.....";
```

Hopefully this won't mess your special characters.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is encoding the `NavigateUrl` property.

Use [decodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp) in your js function.

Comment: Now it's true, but the accents are still having problems as 'Assento para bebÃªs

Comment: @tomcamara - maybe try [unescape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp)?

Answer (score 1):

Having a utility function such as this in a class called, say `StringUtil`:

```
public static string JsEncode(string text)
{
    StringBuilder safe = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char ch in text)
    {
        // Hex encode "\xFF"
        if (ch <= 127)
            safe.Append("\\x" + ((int)ch).ToString("x2"));
        // Unicode hex encode "\uFFFF"
        else
            safe.Append("\\u" + ((int)ch).ToString("x4"));
    }
    return safe.ToString();
}
```

... mean you can then encode the values as safe, JavaScript-encoded strings:

```
hplDetails.NavigateUrl = "JavaScript:GetSpecialEquipmentsDetails('" + StringUtil.JSEncode( ((SGViagens.Entities.SpecialEquipment)(e.Item.DataItem)).EquipmentCode + "','" + ((SGViagens.Entities.SpecialEquipment)(e.Item.DataItem)).EquipmentName ) + "')";
```